# How to add a color thick border top of a card in Android

Tags: android, xml

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It gives this:

[image]

How can I add a color border at the top.

[image]

Comment: Well, from someone who doesn't know android, the most obvious suggestion would be: have you tried adding a new `item` with a red colour and specify the position you want it at?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Where would it go in my XML?

Comment: replace your xml with this

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="5dp"> //change this
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Is this replacing my XML?

Comment: It works except it removes the "card ui" look that I was trying to achieve :(

Comment: show me the card with the background style and your card code please

Comment: The XML I provided is what gives the card view but I think you mean the layout itself?